# Why can the lifetimes reported by ip address be slightly higher than the content of a received IPv6 Router Advertisement?

Tags: debian, ip, ipv6, iproute

I'm currently investigating a strange network issue.

Consider the following IPv6 Router Advertisement (note the **prefix lifetimes**, 5400 and 2700, respectively.):

```
$ rdisc6 -1 wlan0
Soliciting ff02::2 (ff02::2) on wlan0...

Hop limit                 :           64 (      0x40)
Stateful address conf.    :          Yes
Stateful other conf.      :          Yes
Mobile home agent         :           No
Router preference         :       medium
Neighbor discovery proxy  :           No
Router lifetime           :         1800 (0x00000708) seconds
Reachable time            :      3600000 (0x0036ee80) milliseconds
Retransmit time           :  unspecified (0x00000000)
 Recursive DNS server     : 2a02:####:####:####:f2af:85ff:fe11:70d
  DNS server lifetime     :          300 (0x0000012c) seconds
 Prefix                   : 2a02:####:####:####::/64
  On-link                 :          Yes
  Autonomous address conf.:          Yes
  Valid time              :         5400 (0x00001518) seconds
  Pref. time              :         2700 (0x00000a8c) seconds
 Route                    : 2a02:####:####:####::/62
  Route preference        :       medium
  Route lifetime          :         5400 (0x00001518) seconds
 Route                    : ::/0
  Route preference        :       medium
  Route lifetime          :         1800 (0x00000708) seconds
 Source link-layer address: ##:##:##:##:##:##
 from fe80::f2af:85ff:fe11:70d
```

I have observed that the lifetimes reported for one particular address are sometimes slightly *higher* than the values in the router advertisement.

```
inet6 2a02:####:####:####:2f89:f9d2:504f:595d/64 (...)
   valid_lft 5401sec preferred_lft 2701sec
```

(This output is handcrafted. I cannot get a live capture right now because of the network issue I'm ultimately trying to solve, but it is representative of how the lifetimes can be **a second or so higher** than the RA value.)

Why would that be?

I'm currently considering whether this is a possible bug in the network stack that is used in Debian (12), because I'm also observing the following:

This is a router advertisement with both prefix lifetimes set to 0, and as far as I understand, this is not an error, but the router is deliberately trying to invalidate that prefix.

```
$ rdisc6 -1 wlan0
Soliciting ff02::2 (ff02::2) on wlan0...

Hop limit                 :           64 (      0x40)
Stateful address conf.    :          Yes
Stateful other conf.      :          Yes
Mobile home agent         :           No
Router preference         :       medium
Neighbor discovery proxy  :           No
Router lifetime           :         1800 (0x00000708) seconds
Reachable time            :      3600000 (0x0036ee80) milliseconds
Retransmit time           :  unspecified (0x00000000)
 Recursive DNS server     : 2a02:####:####:####:f2af:85ff:fe11:70d
  DNS server lifetime     :          300 (0x0000012c) seconds
 Prefix                   : 2a02:####:####:####::/64
  On-link                 :          Yes
  Autonomous address conf.:          Yes
  Valid time              :            0 (0x00000000) seconds
  Pref. time              :            0 (0x00000000) seconds
 Route                    : ::/0
  Route preference        :       medium
  Route lifetime          :         1800 (0x00000708) seconds
 Source link-layer address: ##:##:##:##:##:##
 from fe80::f2af:85ff:fe11:70d
```

In this case, the `preferred_lft` reported by `ip address` *also* varies by 1 second (while the `valid_lft` just seems to tick down normally from 5400s in real-time). In practice, when I spam `ip address`, `preferred_lft` periodically toggles between 1s and 0s.

Furthermore, `ip monitor` outputs this about every few seconds:

```
2: wlan0    inet6 2a02:####:####:####:2f89:f9d2:504f:595d/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute
       valid_lft 4916sec preferred_lft 1sec
2: wlan0    inet6 2a02:####:####:####:2f89:f9d2:504f:595d/64 scope global deprecated dynamic noprefixroute
       valid_lft 4915sec preferred_lft 0sec
2: wlan0    inet6 2a02:####:####:####:2f89:f9d2:504f:595d/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute
       valid_lft 4913sec preferred_lft 1sec
2: wlan0    inet6 2a02:####:####:####:2f89:f9d2:504f:595d/64 scope global deprecated dynamic noprefixroute
       valid_lft 4912sec preferred_lft 0sec
(and so on)
```

This also causes severe `/var/log/syslog` spam:

```
2023-12-19T19:22:15.143458+01:00 ... avahi-daemon[458]: Registering new address record for 2a02:####:####:####:2f89:f9d2:504f:595d on wlan0.*.
2023-12-19T19:22:16.181261+01:00 ... avahi-daemon[458]: Withdrawing address record for 2a02:####:####:####:2f89:f9d2:504f:595d on wlan0.
2023-12-19T19:22:18.011506+01:00 ... avahi-daemon[458]: Registering new address record for 2a02:####:####:####:2f89:f9d2:504f:595d on wlan0.*.
2023-12-19T19:22:19.240632+01:00 ... avahi-daemon[458]: Withdrawing address record for 2a02:####:####:####:2f89:f9d2:504f:595d on wlan0.
(and so on)
```

This behavior is certainly unwanted. The arbitrary addition of a small value to the preferred lifetime in the router advertisement could explain this partly.

I was able to observe this on Debian 12 and Raspberry Pi OS.

I was **not** able to observe this on Arch Linux and Lubuntu.

Tested on 3 different devices.

*However, tests may not be conclusive* because I cannot control my router, and it does not always send the same router advertisements, and I do not have an isolated test environment.

Comment: What software do you have handling Router Advertisements? The kernel itself (autoconf=1), or systemd-networkd, or dhcpcd, or NetworkManager, or more than one of them?